# STOMP Messages not reaching queue

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to send a message that the client inputs into the browser to a queue using STOMP and ActiveMQ. The STOMP connection is successful from the readouts I get in the console. I am not receiving errors and am using the line:

```
stompClient.send("/queue/testQSource", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
```

in my index.html to do so. However, when I check the ActiveMQ console after inputting into the browser, there is no addition to testQSource. Am I using the correct STOMP syntax to make this happen? Do I need to add any sources at the top of the HTML file other than the STOMP source?

The queue is instantiated here in the camel route:

```
        <from uri="jms:queue:testQSource"/>
        <to uri="securityBean"/>
        <log message="Routing message from testQSource to testQDestination queue with data ${body}"/>
        <to uri="jms:queue:testQDestination"/>
        <to uri="activationBean"/>
        <log message="message: ${body}"/>
```

**EDIT**

I am now getting a message through, but am receiving the following warning:

```
WARN : org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding - Cannot determine specific JmsMessage type to use from body class. Will use generic JmsMessage. Body class: hello.HelloMessage. If you want to send a POJO then your class might need to implement java.io.Serializable, or you can force a specific type by setting the jmsMessageType option on the JMS endpoint.
```

I believe this is because the STOMP message is of a different form than the queue and/or route are expecting. However, I am not sure how to configure my route in a way that will allow me to use my STOMP message. Any tips?

Comment: The URI in camel route config contains JMS but STOMP is different. Did you try putting stomp instead of jms?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tough to say without more information but my first guess is that the stomp client connection is being closed before the message gets a chance to be written to the socket or read by ActiveMQ.  You might want to consider doing a blocking put to the queue by adding a request id to the out-bound frame and wait for the Broker to send you a response frame.  This will ensure that your message is posted prior to the connection being closed.

How you perform the blocking put depends on the client you are using so you need to review the documentation to see what the correct means of doing so is.  Usually there is either a sync send method or the client adds the '[receipt](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Header_receipt)' header to the frame and then doing a blocking receive until you get back a RECEIPT frame with the correctly matching '[receipt-id](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#RECEIPT)' header.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting on the stomp port on the ActiveMQ server ?
As seen in the config (activemq.xml) under "transportConnector"
stomp needs to connect on port 61613 on a default configuration.

Using Node.js with "stomp-client" and a default ActiveMQ server on localhost:

```
var my_client = new Stomp('127.0.0.1', 61613, 'admin', 'admin');
```